# Rapid Serial Port writing to Arduino from Processing

Tags: java, c, embedded, serial-port, processing

I need some help speeding up writing to serial.  I found a few similar questions to this but nothing that dealt with the Processing language or Java so I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue I have.

**edit**

As John points out below, it appears serial just isn't fast enough to send this much data at the speed I want.  Does anyone know of other arduino interfaces that are available?

**end edit**

I am using an arduino to control a grid of 400 RGB LEDs I have hooked up.  To send commands to the arduino I wrote a small program in Processing that manipulates a large array that represents the LEDs.  I am then attempting to update the grid by sending 800 bytes of data to the arduino every 20ms at 115200 baud over serial.  The Processing code that is called every 20ms is:

```
  noStroke();
  int dataPos = 0; // position in LED data array
  byte[] dataLedGrid = new byte[400*2]; // array for bytes to send
  for(int j=0; j<LEDS_TALL; j++) {
    for(int i=0; i<LEDS_WIDE; i++) {
      int pos = j*20+i;
      int r = ledGrid[LEDS_WIDE-i-1][LEDS_TALL-j-1][0], g = ledGrid[LEDS_WIDE-i-1][LEDS_TALL-j-1][1] ,b = ledGrid[LEDS_WIDE-i-1][LEDS_TALL-j-1][2];
      int colorData = ((g & 0x1F) << 10) | ((b & 0x1F) << 5) | (r & 0x1F);
      dataLedGrid[dataPos] = byte(colorData & 0x00FF);
      dataLedGrid[dataPos+1] = byte(colorData & 0xFF00);
      dataPos+=2;

      // draw LED squares on gui
      fill(ledGrid[i][j][0], ledGrid[i][j][1], ledGrid[i][j][2]);
      rect(SIDE_PANEL_WIDTH+(LED_SQUARE_SIDE+LED_SQUARE_SPACING)*i+HORIZONTAL_MARGIN,
      (LED_SQUARE_SIDE+LED_SQUARE_SPACING)*j+VERTICAL_MARGIN, 
      LED_SQUARE_SIDE, LED_SQUARE_SIDE);
    }
  }
  myPort.write(dataLedGrid); // write to serial
```

On the arduino I have a 1D array (Display) that represents the grid on the arduino side.  The loop code is:

```
void loop() {

  unsigned int pos, c1, c2;

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    for(byte j=0; j<20; ++j) {
        for(byte i=0; i<20; ++i) {
          c1 = Serial.read();
          c2 = Serial.read();

          pos = i+20*j;
          if(j % 2 != 0)         // it's a square of leds created by a zigzaging line
            pos = 20*(j+1)-i-1;  // so I have to reverse every other line

          Display[pos] = (unsigned int)(c1<<8 | c2);
        }
    }
    show();
  }
}
```

Now the code itself works fine but when the serial writing slows everything down.  When I run the Processing code without the serial writing everything is fine an runs at the intended speed.  However, when I add the serial writing in, everything becomes slightly choppy.  The CPU doesn't max out or anything so I'm assuming it's the serial.write method I am calling.  What can I do to speed up this code or remove the lag from serial writing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Do the math.

115200 baud is, at 8-N-1, 11,520 bytes per second, or 86.8 usec/byte.

In 20 msec, you can send 230.4 bytes.  Sending 800 bytes will take about 70 msec.

Trying to send 800 bytes at 115200 baud every 20 msec isn't going to work.

Comment: Wow, I must of calculated that wrong. Any ideas of what I can do to get 800 bytes to the arduino every 20 ms?

Comment: Just to note, RS-232 serial ports have to spend about 10 bit times to send a single byte due to protocol overhead.  This overhead is actually included in John's math here.

Comment: @William, not familiar with the available interfaces, but you could use USB or SPI.  You need about 320 kBaud from what I see here.

Comment: @William: If sequential frames differ very little from each other, you could just send the differences from the previous frame rather than re-sending the entire frame each time.

Comment: 115200bps is too slow, but with 460800bps or 921600bps it is not a problem. Widnows supports these speeds, but RS232 built in motherboards rarely support higher then 115200. Therefore he needs to buy PCI card which has 921600bps RS232, or USB<=>RS232 convertor cable which supports these high speeds (If I remember well FTDI based ones will do the job). If AVR is not interrupted by anything else during RX receive, then this is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `Serial.setTimeout(0)` to the `setup()` of your arduino sketch

Comment: hey... perhaps you might want to explain why making the suggested changes will solve the problem in question...